# callback(); is an undefined function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, async.js

Hey guys i have this code running in node.js:

```js
function syncVout(transaction, vouts, Voutcallback){
async.each(vouts, function(vout, callback){
    database('vout').insert({
        'transaction': transaction,
        'value': vout['value'] * 100000000,
        'n': vout['n'],
        'asm': vout['scriptPubKey']['asm'],
        'hex': vout['scriptPubKey']['hex'],
        'reqSigs': vout['scriptPubKey']['reqSigs'],
        'type': vout['scriptPubKey']['type']
    }).then(function () {
        syncVoutAddresses(vout['scriptPubKey']['hex'], vout['scriptPubKey']['addresses'], function(){
           callback(); //<---- Error on this line!
        });
    }).catch(function(err){
        error(err + "Vouts");
       callback(); //<---- Error on this line!
    });
}, function(err, res){
    if(err){error(err + "Vouts");}
    Voutcallback();//<---- Error on this line!
});
}

function syncVoutAddresses(vouthex, addresses, callback){
    database('vout').select('id').where({'hex': vouthex}).then(function(rows){
        if(rows[0] != undefined){
            connectVoutAddress(addresses, rows[0]['id'], function(){
               callback(); //<---- Error on this line!
            });
        }else{
            callback(); //<---- Error on this line!
        }
    }).catch(function(err){
        error(err);
        callback(); //<---- Error on this line!
    });
}
```

**Edit** calling `syncVout`:

```js
async.series([
  syncVin(rows[0]['id'], vin),
  syncVout(rows[0]['id'], vout)
], function(err, res) {
  //Write error
  if (err) {
    error(err);
  }
  callback();
});
```

On the marked lines i get this error:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

What did i wrong? Can someone suggest me a solution to make the callbacks working?

Comment: You need to pass an array of functions to `async.series()`.  The interpreter is calling `syncVin(rows[0]['id'], vin)` immediately and passing the return result to `async.series()` which is apparently `undefined`.  You probably need an anonymous function wrapper that can be called later.

Comment: @jfriend00 this was the solution thanks :) Can you write an answer so i can mark it?

Comment: Did any of these answers solve your issue? If so, please mark the best answer as the accepted answer by checking the green checkmark to the left of that answer to indicate to the community that your question has been answered and then both you and the person who provided the answer will earn some reputation points that can lead to more privileges here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

`async.series()` takes an array of functions.  Your code is executing the functions in the array and passing `async.series()` the return value of those functions which is apparently `undefined`.  Instead, you need to make the `syncVin` and `syncVout` calls into anonymous functions so they can be called LATER by the async library rather than immediately by the interpreter.

```
async.series([
  function(callback) {syncVin(rows[0]['id'], vin, callback)},
  function(callback) {syncVout(rows[0]['id'], vout, callback)}
], function(err, res) {
  //Write error
  if (err) {
    error(err);
  }
  // both functions done here
});
```

And, you have to make sure that `syncVin() and`syncVOut()` properly call their passed in callback when they are complete.

I don't quite follow all the rest of the code so this could be just the first thing you need to fix.

Comment: @Alesfatalis - Per your request, I turned my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```js
async.series([
  function(callback) {
    syncVin(rows[0]['id'], vin, function() {
      callback();
    });
  },
  function(callback) {
    syncVout(rows[0]['id'], vout, function() {
      callback();
    });
  }
], function(err, res) {
  //Write error
  if (err) {
    error(err);
  }
  callback();
});
```